# mvn fails to find HTMLUnitDriver dependency during project install

Tags: maven, selenium

maven suggests:
Starting with 2.53.0 you need to explicitly include HtmlUnitDriver as a dependency to include it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
</dependency>
```

However, build fails not being able to resolve the dependency.

>

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.648 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-24T14:49:18+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/118M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project maven_selenium_project_sample: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.samplecompany:maven_selenium_project_sample:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.20 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project maven_selenium_project_sample: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.samplecompany:maven_selenium_project_sample:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.20 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `0` in the version like this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the error: what you are asking for does not exist at Maven Central. You need either:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
</dependency>
```

or:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or one of the other possible versions from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cselenium-htmlunit-driver).